# jQuery UI breaks the anchor download attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, button, anchor

[My First Post]

Relevant info:

- [download attribute](http://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute)
- [jquery-ui](https://jqueryui.com/)

Statement:

I am using jQuery UI, and have no errors. All my buttons and styled elements behave correctly. During a jQuery UI modification to a link I discovered that an html5 functionality broke. This link currently downloads a base64 encoded file that was generated by another function. I want to note that prior to the modification the file downloads perfectly. Here is the pre-modification working code.

JS

```
data = '<a download="out.yaml" href="data:text/yaml;base64, '+ encoded +'" > Yaml Output Download</a> ;

document.getElementById( "output").innerHTML = data ;
```

HTML

```
<div id="output">
</div>
```

When I modify to add jQuery UI to the anchor by adding

```
class="button"
```

the download functionality stops but the styling is implemented and no errors are given by chrome

broken code:

JS

```
data = '<a class="button" download="out.yaml" href="data:text/yaml;base64, '+ encoded +'" > Yaml Output Download</a> ;

document.getElementById( "output").innerHTML = data ;
```

HTML

```
<div id="output">
</div>
```

I believe that this is a jQuery UI problem, but would like to know if there is a way to use the jQuery UI button while maintaining the original download capability.

EDIT

JS
     data = ' Yaml Output Download ;

```
 //document.getElementById( "output" ).innerHTML = data ;
 $( '#output' ).html( data ) ;
 $( document ).ready( function() { reload() ; } ) ;
```

ONLOAD

```
function reload() {
    $( "input[type=submit], a.button, button" )
        .button()
        .click(function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
} ;

$(function() {
    reload() ;
});
```

SOLOUTION

Since I thought the reloading function was being executed correctly I didn't go back and look at the reload function as jQueryUI was not throwing errors or not functioning. All that was needed to be done was to comment out event.preventDefault() ; which as the name suggests prevents the triggering of the default action, in this case the download of the file.

ONLOAD

```
   function reload() {
        $( "input[type=submit], a.button, button" )
            .button()
            .click(function( event ) {
                //event.preventDefault();
            });
    } ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible the javascript snippet (document.getElementById) needs
to run within the jQuery document.ready callback?  Regardless of whether
that is the issue, I recommend executing your javascript from within
the document.ready callback, as opposed to leaving the javascript to run
as the page is loaded.

Comment: even when using $( '#output' ).html( data ) ; the results are the same

Comment: Thanks your answer lead me into the right direction, the reloading of the function was being done correctly hence I didn't go back and look at the reload function as jQueryUI was not throwing errors or not functioning. I had to comment out event.preventDefault() ; which as the name suggests prevents the triggering of the default action.